# How do i get passed an empty key in a php array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

how to i get to the arrays content if it doesnt have a key like this

```
$products[0]
```

this will get me partially there but how to i get past []

```
( [0] => Array 
( [] => Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [product_name] => stuff i need to get to  )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is very strange. You could try

```
$products[0][''][0]['product_name']
```

Comment: Good idea. It's likely that the code generating this array has a typo or something that's setting the key to the empty string. Of course, you may also need to append `['product_name']` to this answer to get all the way to the 'stuff i need ...'

Comment: @grossvogel: oops, yeah I missed that out.

Answer (score 1):

```
$products[0][""][0]["product_name"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use var_dump or var_export to print your array and you will see its an empty string.
print_r will give you output like that for empty strings.